# Вернуть переменную java

Tags: java, ооп

Есть класс `RandomNumbers` и есть класс `Extrema`. Класс `Extrema` наследует значения класса `RandomNumbers`. В классе `One` есть функция `FuncOne()` в классе `Extrema`, две функций `Max()` `Min()`. Которые определяют максимум и минимум массива, проблема в чем.

```
public double Minimum(){
   for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
      if(MinMass > X[i]){
         MinMass = X[i];
        }
      }
   return MinMass;
}
```

И когда я использую `MinMass` в классе `RandomNumbers` она почему то равно нулю.

Класс `RandomNumbers`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomNumbers {

double[] X = new double[100]; //Случайные велечины double[] H = new double[5]; //Частоты double max = 1.0; double min = 0.0; double MaxMass; //Максимум double MinMass; //Минимум

public void Pirson(){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        Random random = new Random();
        X[i] = (max-min)* random.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(X[i]);
        Extrema extrema = new Extrema();
        extrema.Minimum();
        extrema.Maximum();
        if(X[i] > MinMass && X[i] < 0.2 ) {
            H[0]++;
        }else if(X[i] > 0.2 && X[i] < 0.4){
            H[1]++;
        }else if(X[i] > 0.4 && X[i] < 0.6){
            H[2]++;
        }else if(X[i] > 0.6 && X[i] < 0.8){
            H[3]++;
        }else if(X[i] > 0.8 && X[i] < MaxMass){
            H[4]++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "Первый отрезок " +H[0] + " \n");
    System.out.println("Второй отрезок " +H[1] + " \n");
    System.out.println("Третий отрезок " +H[2] + " \n");
    System.out.println("Четвертый отрезок " +H[3] + " \n");
    System.out.println("Пятый отрезок " +H[4] + " \n");

    System.out.println("Максимум:" + MaxMass);
    System.out.println("Минимум:" + MinMass);
    }   
}
```

Класс `Extrema`:

```
public class Extrema extends RandomNumbers {
    public double Minimum(){
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
            MinMass = X[0];
            if(MinMass > X[i]){
                MinMass = X[i];
            }
        }
        return MinMass;
    }
    public double Maximum(){
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
            MaxMass = X[0];
            if(MaxMass < X[i]){
                MaxMass = X[i];
            }
        }
        return MaxMass;
    }
}
```

Comment: кинь лучше подробный код

Comment: Добавил только начал учить, решил попробовать хоть что то написать) Все считает, только максимум и минимум по нулям

Comment: во первых, у Вас в коде не хватает объявленных переменных (или констант) `max` и `min`. Во вторых не хватает массива `H`, также у Вас не объявлены переменные `MinMass` и `MaxMass`.

Comment: все объявлено, все работает просто почему то не выводит мин и макс, а пишет 0.0

Comment: Я добавил ниже код с правками, проверьте его :)

Comment: Все равно ничего, выводит 100 рандомных чисел, потом сколько из них попадают в отрезки и максимум и минимум опять ноль(( . И у меня сто чисел между 0 и 1, а не между 0 и 100

Answer (score 1):

Класс `RandomNumbers`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomNumbers {
    //не хватает объявления этих констант и массива    
    final double min = 0;
    final double max = 1;
    int[] H = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0};

    //а также этих переменных
    double MinMass;
    double MaxMass;

    double[] X = new double[100]; //Случайные велечины double[] H = new double[5]; //Частоты double max = 1.0; double min = 0.0; double MaxMass; //Максимум double MinMass; //Минимум

    public void Pirson(){
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
            Random random = new Random();
            X[i] = (max-min)* random.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(X[i]);
            Extrema extrema = new Extrema();
            extrema.Minimum();
            extrema.Maximum();
            if(X[i] > MinMass && X[i] < 0.2 ) {
                H[0]++;
            }else if(X[i] > 0.2 && X[i] < 0.4){
                H[1]++;
            }else if(X[i] > 0.4 && X[i] < 0.6){
                H[2]++;
            }else if(X[i] > 0.6 && X[i] < 0.8){
                H[3]++;
            }else if(X[i] > 0.8 && X[i] < MaxMass){
                H[4]++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "Первый отрезок " +H[0] + " \n");
        System.out.println("Второй отрезок " +H[1] + " \n");
        System.out.println("Третий отрезок " +H[2] + " \n");
        System.out.println("Четвертый отрезок " +H[3] + " \n");
        System.out.println("Пятый отрезок " +H[4] + " \n");

        System.out.println("Максимум:" + MaxMass);
        System.out.println("Минимум:" + MinMass);
    }
}
```

Класс `Extrema`:

```
public class Extrema extends RandomNumbers {
    public double Minimum(){
        MinMass = X[0];    //также, в Вашем коде не хватает этого
        for(int i = 1; i<100; i++) {
            if(MinMass > X[i]){
                MinMass = X[i];
            }
        }
        return MinMass;
    }
    public double Maximum(){
        MaxMass = X[0];    //и этого
        for(int i = 1; i<100; i++){
            if(MaxMass < X[i]){
                MaxMass = X[i];
            }
        }
        return MaxMass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

я могу ошибаться, но на этом участке кода MinMass в каждой итерации цикла приравнивается к Х[0]. Из-за этого внутри if результат храниться до следующей итерации, а потом снова MinMass = X[0];. Т.е. видимо присвоение вне цикла нужно оставить, а это убрать.

`for(int i = 1; i<100; i++) {
            MinMass = X[0];
            if(MinMass > X[i]){
                MinMass = X[i];
            }
        }`

Comment: Я это исправил все равно ляп, мне кажется, что функций просто напросто получают пустые массивы, а не должны же ведь?